# Getting Error When I Try And Play A Sound In Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting an error when I try and play a sound in `pygame`. This is my code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


pygame.mixer.music.load('easy going.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
```

And this is the error it gives me

> File "c:/Users/Isaiah/Desktop/All of my programs/pygame sound.py", line 5, in 
>       pygame.mixer.music.load('easy going.mp3')
>   pygame.error: Couldn't open 'easy going.mp3'

Comment: Seems that the problem is with your .mp3 file, check if the path to the file is correct or try to open another file.

Comment: Where is the file located? Is it under `c:/Users/Isaiah/Desktop/All of my programs/`? If it is and it is still not working, you can try to give it the full path or rename the file `easy going.mp3` to `easy_going.mp3`.

Comment: No, the file is located at

Comment: C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop

Comment: I have it just on my desktop, Do I have to have it in a folder?

Comment: You have to give it the full path to the file (which in this case would be its location your desktop folder). i.e. `"C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\easy going.mp3"`.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and this is what it gave me..

Comment: @martineau, I tried but it gave me this

Comment: @martineau 


File "c:/Users/Isaiah/Desktop/All of my programs/pygame sound.py", line 5 pygame.mixer.music.load('C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\easy_going.mp3') ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX

Comment: Since the path has backslash characters in it you'll need  prefix it with an `r` so it's `r"C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\easy going.mp3"`.

Comment: @martineau, I have to have parenthesis right?

Comment: Yes. `pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\easy going.mp3")`

Comment: @martineau, Ok, No more errors but now I can't hear anything. My computer volume is all the way up.

Comment: Try `pygame.mixer.music.play()`, If that doesn't work, ask a new question.

Comment: @martineau. OK, didn't work. Thank your for all you help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(r"C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\easy_going (online-audio-converter.com).wav")
s = pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound)

#Delay loop
while s.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```

Comment: No, _you_ didn't: [Can't hear the sounds I am tring to play with pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957315/cant-hear-the-sounds-i-am-tring-to-play-with-pygame)