# Can't hear the sounds I am tring to play with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I can't hear the sounds I am trying to play with pygame. This is my code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()



pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\easy_going.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MP3 support is limited with Pygame; use .wav instead. Fortunately you can easily convert .mp3 files to .wav files with an online conversions tool.

You also need to add a delay loop at the end to keep your program from closing prematurely.

Convert your .mp3 to a .wav and then try running this modified code.

```
import pygame

#Replaced init() with mixer.init() 
pygame.mixer.init()

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(r"C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\easy_going.wav")
s = pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound)

#Delay loop
while s.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```

Good luck!

Comment: An important point is that the `pygame.mixer.Sound.play()` only *begins* the playing of the sound, then returns immediately.  If you program then exits, you will not hear anything.

Comment: Thanks You Sooooo Much!

Comment: Also, is there a way I can have a print statement going while I have the music playing?

Comment: Print statement going? Not sure what you mean. Do you want to print something out before or during the music playing, or do you want to take input from the user?

Comment: @ David Greydanus I was trying to make a text based RPG so I wanted background music while they were being asked questions. I just took away the delay and then it worked. I there any way to loop the music it over and over?